# Connecting with SAP systems via .NET without additional payments

Tags: sap-dotnet-connector

I need to connect to SAP and do a simple update but it will be the first time for me connecting to SAP and I know almost nothing. After some search on web, I learned that there is an API which works only in visual studio 2003 (SAP .NET Connector).

But I have a Windows 7 .Net 3.5 SP1 system.

Is there any free way to connect to SAP using Visual Studio 2008 on the system above? (Free means without additional payment. We have an SAP account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the [SAP Portal Development Kit (PDK) for .NET](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/dotnet?rid=/webcontent/uuid/40be5378-bfa9-2b10-399b-ba5719c0b5b8).

These are available for SAP NetWeaver 7.0 and 2004, and versions for Visual Studio 2003, 2005 and 2008 exist.

Other than the PDK, there's only one other product that I know of, but it's not free, although it does have a "free" trial period, and it's quite reasonably priced (at least in comparison to the cost of SAP itself!).

It's the [SAP Explorer & Proxy Generator](http://www.aconcaguait.com/explorerproxygen2008.php) which is available for Visual Studio 2008.  There's also a [version for Visual Studio 2005](http://www.aconcaguait.com/explorerproxygen2005.php).

There's also a number of articles for using the SAP.NET Connector to connect to SAP from Visual Studio 2008 (be aware that some of the solutions may require you to use Visual Studio 2003, at least as an interim measure):

[Connection to SAP from Visual Studio 2008 with SAP.NET Connector 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Connect_SAP_from_VS2008.aspx)
[SAP .NET RFC Server with SAP.NET Connector 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SAP_NET_RFC_Server.aspx)
[Using the SAP .Net Connector in Visual Studio 2008](http://www.dataxstream.com/2009/08/using-the-sap-net-connector-in-visual-studio-2008/)

Comment: thanks for the answer,
can i use portal development kit with asp.net, i just want to connect to sap, and get a record by id. Documentations about the development kit are about creating a portal part. Do you know any sample article including some code

Comment: SAP released the new SAP.NET Connector 3.0 !!

Answer (score 0):

For newer SAP Versions (WAS 620 or later I think) you can use web services. As far as I know every remote enabled function module is exposed as web service.