# Alternatives to the "SAP Connector for .NET"

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector

Are there (free or cheap) alternatives to the "SAP Connector for .NET" ?

Comment: Hmmm - "free or cheap" in the same sentence as SAP - that's something you don't see very often...

Comment: I don't get the question: the “SAP Connector for .NET” actually is free! (Or do you mean something that can be downloaded without having an SAP user account?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually use [ERPConnect](http://www.theobald-software.com/en/products/erpconnect.htm) to work with SAP.
It's possible to call BAPI, read SAP tables, Functions...

The library is very easy to understand. The difficult part for a newbie is to know how is structured a BAPI (import and export parameters).

Comment: (even far from free)

Comment: The link to ERPConnect has changed. It's now: [ERPConnect](https://theobald-software.com/en/erpconnect-productinfo.html)
(answer's edit queue is full)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the rfc library to connect to SAP; there are also some wrappers for the rfc library (but afaik none for .net).

Web services are another alternative and then there is that one commercial product I know about: http://www.theobald-software.com/en/products/erpconnect.htm

(I have no experience with it though.)

You can find some other ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607672/sap-net-connector).

Answer (score 1):

If your ERP's version 5.0 or above, you can directly call web services from the ERP system. No need to use the .NET connector anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's a software called RfcConnector I heard good things about, but I've not used it myself (yet). The product is not free, but they have a free evaluation download available at [their website](http://rfcconnector.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Nor free or cheap, but another good and complete solution is **MuleSoft's SAP Connector**.

Check these links for further information:

- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/sap-connector
- https://www.mulesoft.com/integration-solutions/soa/sap
- https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/sap-r3-business-suite-integration-connector